# Stuck In a Redirect Loop

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I'm trying to build a code where non-members get redirected to the landing page. Unfortunately, the code that I've built works partly and results in a redirect loop.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && function_exists('pmpro_hasMembershipLevel') && pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()) {
    global $current_user;
    $current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);
    echo 'Membership Level: ' . $current_user->membership_level->name;
} else {
    wp_redirect(/my-account/orders/);
    exit;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. The first part of the if statement is working fine but the second half is returning redirect loop.

Thanks and Regards,

Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check if the user is on that particular page or not. If he is on that page, then there is no need to redirect him/her again.

Change your else to this:

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && function_exists('pmpro_hasMembershipLevel') && pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()) {
    global $current_user;
    $current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);
    echo 'Membership Level: ' . $current_user->membership_level->name;
} else {
    if( ! is_page('page-slug') ){
        wp_redirect('/my-account/orders/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

In which `page-slug` is the slug of the page you are redirecting your users to.